# Check if record has been modified, if not dirty

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form, that when closed and dirty, saves the record and refreshes the page from where it was called.

The problem I have is that some of the fields in the form commit the edits when a combo is changed, or after update etc. As other fields are calculated on their values.

The problem I have is that if I change a value in a combo box and the changes are committed, at the time of closing, the form is no longer dirty.

Is there a way to check if the or **IS or WAS** dirty since opened? The only way I can think to do it is something like;

```
if me.dirty = true or NewTimeStamp <> OldTimeStamp then
```

Comment: "Is there a way to check if the **or** IS or WAS dirty since opened?" ...did you mean "form"? Also, have you tried the way you were thinking yet? How did it go?

Comment: Yeah sorry, form. I tried to delcare Oldts as Date as set it as the value of the timestamp when the form was loaded and compare it against the timestamp when closing the form. But the variable was always blank. Ended up setting a hidden textbox with the OldTs value and comparing it. Its not ideal, as it means I have to edit a lot of forms.